# One object turns gray in rendered/cycles view

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

I know this has been asked before, but my issue doesn't seem to be the same as anyone else's. One of my objects renders just fine in the viewport and under Eevee, but disappears into the solid gray background when rendered with Cycles. It's still clipping the viewport grid that it sits on top of, but not the other objects in the scene.

[image: Imgur]

There is no texture on this object, it is simply rendered as a material with a base colour and material properties.

So far, I've confirmed that:

- The object's viewport display settings in the context menu are correct. (set to textured)
- Changing material properties doesn't make any difference, and the material works fine on other objects in the scene.
- The normals are "normal"
- The lighting is adequate
- The object ("Engine") is enabled in the view layer for rendering, viewport, everything.

I even deleted the object, loaded an old save, and copypasta'd it back into the scene. Same result. Really frustrating.

Does anyone know how I can get it back?

File: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52552

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this after watching a few YouTube videos.

Above "Viewport Display" and within "Visibility" in the properties tab, there's special settings for "Ray Visibility" which is essentially for Cycles' ray-tracing algorithm.

[image: Imgur]

Helpful to know about if you want coarse-grained control over rendering. (Use nodes/shading for fine control).